# Do OAuth 1 tokens work with Gmail API?

Tags: oauth, gmail, imap, google-oauth, gmail-api

[Gmail released a new API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) and [since the auth scope is the same as for IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes), it looks like IMAP access tokens will work on the Gmail API.

What is unclear is if OAuth 1 tokens will work on the Gmail API. I have legacy OAuth 1 tokens I'm considering migrating from IMAP to the Gmail API but I cannot ask the users to update their credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail API does not support the deprecated Oauth1 standard.  A forward-path for upgrading those tokens to Oauth2 (without user involvement) can be found:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration